# Regarding a quantity being negligible compared to another (limit definition)

Tags: limits, numerical-methods, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, mathematical-modeling

I was watching a lecture on Asymptotic Expansions, and there was a part where:

$\arctan(\epsilon)$ was said to be approximately $\epsilon -\frac{\epsilon^3}{3}+\frac{\epsilon^5}{5}+...$ (Taylor series centered at 0). With the approximation being more accurate with how small $\epsilon$ is.

We can then take $\arctan(\epsilon) = \epsilon + R$ where $R$ is the error (i.e. remaining terms of the infinite series).

Then the presenter says that for this approximation to be accurate, there's a sense in which $R$ must be negligible compared to the approximation term $\epsilon$. He writes $R \ll \epsilon$.

Alternatively, he says $\frac{R}{\epsilon} \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. Can you help me understand why these two statements are equivalent? $R \ll \epsilon$ and $\frac{R}{\epsilon} \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Thanks!

Comment: You can take $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}\to 0$ as $x\to x_0$ as *definition* of $f(x)\ll g(x)$. Note that different choices of $x_0$ may lead to different notions of $\ll$.

Comment: But why can I take it as a definition? Is it because for $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}\to 0$ to be true, $f(x)$ must go to $0$ faster than $g(x)$? Even if so, the notion of "negligible" implies a certain extreme degree of comparison, so wouldn't we need $f(x) \to 0$ MUCH faster than $g(x) \to 0$? How does $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}\to 0$ convey that information?

Comment: @alwaysiamcaesar: the statement that $f(x) $ tends to $0$ much faster than $g(x) \to 0$ is an informal / crude way of saying that $f(x) /g(x) \to 0$. The statement does not have any independent meaning.

Comment: Most of the confusion in calculus is created because people assume meanings of various statements by default instead of looking at definitions.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ok, so do the statements "$f(x)$ tends to 0 faster than $g(x)$ does" and "$f(x)$ tends to 0 MUCH faster than $g(x)$ does" both imply the same thing? That is they both imply $\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}\to 0$? If so, what's the significance of using the $<<$ sign as apposed to just $<$?

Comment: Yes both the statements are crude and imprecise. The real meaning is in the equation $f/g\to 0$.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks.

Comment: The symbol $<<$ is also very context dependent and without further information one can't give a meaning to it.

Comment: Also note that most calculus texts try to avoid defining confusing terms and hope the student catches their meaning somehow.

Comment: You can have $0<f(x)<g(x)$ by setting $g(x)=2f(x)$. These however converge to zero $0=g(x_0)$ at the same speed (or order, if integer powers of $ϵ=x-x_0$ can be extracted).